# Ubuntu on Thinkpad W530

Tags: thinkpad, compatibility, input-devices, amixer

Is this a good idea? I'm new to Linux but am not afraid of the research and work to get it working properly, presuming it will eventually work. I've seen it's not certified by Ubuntu, but the W540 is.

Thoughts? Suggestions?

I will be running a Linux distro exclusively, no dual-boot.

This is my personal/work computer. I will also use it for audio mixing and editing. Would like to install Studio One and Capture to integrate with a Presonus Studio Live digital mixer.

Thanks!

Chris

Answer (score 0):

Since you're not going for a dual-boot and the hardware is neither very old or very new, you'll likely have a fairly easy first time installing and setting up Ubuntu.

A surprise to many people, the user version of Ubuntu is very easy to install and setup. It even provides a friendly Windows-esque install GUI (although a less sophisticated version also exists with the distro, if you're feeling adventurous). Plus, the benefits of a free, fast OS are simply wonderful.

The majority of issues I've encountered in Ubuntu involved obscure or very outdated hardware. For nearly everything, Ubuntu will generally find a driver. Even when it fails, though, it's usually possible to find a workaround on the internet.